# tcolorbox boxes in last line are slightly misaligned

Tags: pdftex, margins, tcolorbox, alignment, hfill

The following code utilizes the `tcolorbox` package to create a template of a round rectangle `gamebox`. A simple `\foreach` statement prints gamebox with the strings `Lv. 0` to `Lv. 103` printed on them. I nulled `before` and overrode `after` to `\hfill` so that the boxes are well-aligned, making it easy to cut them. `\noindent` was included in the loop to prevent the first line's indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.7cm,right=0.7cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

\newtcbox{\gamebox} {
fontupper=\fontsize{0.7cm}{0.7cm}\selectfont\bfseries,
width=3cm,
boxrule=0.1cm,
height=1.5cm,
halign=center,
valign=center,
before=,
after=\hfill,
tcbox width=forced center
}

\foreach \i in {0,...,103} {
    \noindent
    \gamebox{Lv. \i}
}
\end{document}
```

However the last line(96 to 103) of the PDF output is a bit off. Regardless of how I adjust the page margins and box sizes, the last line seems to have a slightly smaller `\hfill` than the others, and the difference becomes noticeable in the latter columns. Does `LaTeX` reserve space for the end of the last line by default? If so how can I disable this function to get a perfect 8x13 placement?

Answer (score 3):

You have after every box an `\hfill` provided by the `tcolorbox`, a normal space (the one introduced by the end-of-line after `\gamebox{Lv. \i}`, which can shrink or stretch a little), and a final space after you close the `\foreach`, after the last `}`. Finally, there is an end-of-paragraph, which makes the normal spaces their nominal size (more or less, I think it's an `\hfil`). So the spaces in the normal lines and the last one are not exactly the same size.

[image]

You can for example remove the last (end-of-paragraph) space with an `\unskip` at the end:

```
...    
    \gamebox{Lv. \i}
}\unskip
...
```

[image]

Or remove every spurious space:

```
...
\foreach \i in {0,...,103} {%
    \noindent
    \gamebox{Lv. \i}%
}%
...
```

[image]

Anyway, to put things in a grid, I would use a tabular structure (and `tcolorbox` has a "roster" functionality) to create similar things.